# Handling 500 / Maximum request length exceeded in an API client friendly way

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an ASP.NET hosted WebAPI endpoint for uploading files (multipart form-data). The expected files are going to be small so I'm going to leave the default max request size in place (4MB). When the request size is violated, by default the framework wants to return an HTML centric response. I'd like to return something more API client friendly.

Because of the way IIS and the ASP.NET pipeline works, request size violations do not appear to be handled by anything in the WebAPI pipeline such as MessageHandlers. Therefore, I've resorted to catching the error in the Global.asax.cs and redirecting to a controller which creates an API client friendly response.

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    if (exception.Message.ToUpper().Contains("MAXIMUM REQUEST LENGTH"))
    {
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Redirect("~/errors/500?message=" + exception.Message);
    }
}

public class ErrorsController : ApiController
{
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id, string message)
   {
      return Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)id, message);
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'd love to be able to handle this sort of thing without issuing a 302 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked everywhere for a way to invoke an API controller from with Application_Error and cannot find a solution.

The closest I got is below.

However, this code results in a 'System.NullReferenceException' occurring in System.Web.Http.DLL.

I believe this is because the HttpRequestMessage is incomplete...its Headers and Properties are null but i'm not sure what needs to go in there to make it work:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e){

        // Other code omitted for brevity

        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

        // Set the RouteData to point to the desired controller and action to invoke
        IHttpRouteData routeData = new HttpRouteData(new HttpRoute());
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Get");
        routeData.Values.Add("id", "500");
        routeData.Values.Add("message", exception.Message);

        // Avoid IIS7 returning its own stock error pages
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        // Call target Controller and pass the routeData.
        System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController errorController = new ErrorController();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri),
        };

        errorController.ExecuteAsync(
            new HttpControllerContext(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration, routeData, request),
            CancellationToken.None
        );
```

TrySkipIisCustomErrors Reference: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Apr/29/IIS-7-Error-Pages-taking-over-500-Errors